# rmarkdown escape html in kable

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown, kable

I am trying to give my kable table's cells some custom HTML classes. But the issues is that the div gets encoded like if it was the content of the cell.
I remember the shiny tables have a way to make the content of the celle escape and be interpreted as is.
Is there such a thing for rmarkdown/knitr ?

For instance:

```
make_green  function(x) {
    x <- paste('<div class="button is-success">',x,">/div>")

    return(x)
}

new_df <- iris %>% mutate(speci = make_green(Species))
kable(head(new_df))
```

returns something like this:

```
<td style="text-align:right;"> 5.1 </td>
<td style="text-align:right;"> 3.5 </td>
<td style="text-align:right;"> 1.4 </td>
<td style="text-align:right;"> 0.2 </td>
<td style="text-align:left;"> setosa </td>
<td style="text-align:left;"> &lt;div class=&quot;button is-success&quot;&gt; setosa &lt;/div&gt; </td>
```

but I'd like it to return something like:

```
<td style="text-align:right;"> 5.1 </td>
<td style="text-align:right;"> 3.5 </td>
<td style="text-align:right;"> 1.4 </td>
<td style="text-align:right;"> 0.2 </td>
<td style="text-align:left;"> setosa </td>
<td style="text-align:left;"> <div class="button is-success"> setosa 
</div</td>
```

Here is the difference between the when rendering

[image: difference between the 2]

Answer (score 5):

Use `escape = FALSE`:

```
kable(head(new_df), format = "html", escape = FALSE)
```